# How to deal with elastic scattering if $|\vec k| \ne |\vec k'|$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

I know that for elastic scattering we can use the Lippmann-Schwinger equation to get $f(\theta)$ in the form:
$$ f(\theta)=-\frac{m}{2\pi \hbar^2} \int e^{-i\vec k' \cdot \vec r'} V(\vec{r}') \psi(\vec r') d^3r'$$
however the typical derivation of this result relies on the fact that $|\vec k'|=|\vec k|$. My question is what is the applicability of this result when $|\vec k'|\ne |\vec k|$ but we still have elastic scattering? Can we still use it or do we have to take another approach to solving the problem (either way please can you explain)?  (Here $|k|$ is the initial wavenumber and $|k'|$ is the final of the particle which is being scattered).

Comment: What do you mean by elastic scattering if the momentum changes? If the momentum of the initial particle is not conserved, that is inelastic scattering

Comment: @Ismasou i.e. no particles are created or destroyed i.e. the total kinetic energy remains constant. I am assuming that the thing we are scattering of takes some of the kinetic energy.

Comment: That is elastic scattering, when you go to the mass reference frame you'll have |k|=|k'|

Comment: @Ismasou what do you mean by the 'mass reference frame'? The center of mass frame? - if so then what is $|k|$?

Comment: Exactly, in the center of mass reference of the scattering, you cannot get elastic scattering with different final  momentum. It's just impossible

Comment: @Ismasou so I am guessing that $|k|$ is then the wavenumber of one of the particles (it will be the same for both) - is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's the definition of elastic scattering

Answer (score 0):

If $|\vec{k}|\ne|\vec{k}'|$, then $E\ne E'$ and you don't have elastic scattering; rather, you've got inelastic scattering.